# What cause java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: when trying to replace json array asset file to api Json array data?

Tags: java, android, json, exoplayer2.x

Instead of passing/reading data from json asset file, i am trying to use direct JSON data from api. (i am passing json array data using Intent)

Same content data of json asset is using in api.

is previous code (it read data from JSON asset file)

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_chooser_activity);
    sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter();
    ExpandableListView sampleListView = findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
    sampleListView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
    sampleListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String dataUri = intent.getDataString();
    String[] uris;
    if (dataUri != null) {
      uris = new String[] {dataUri};
    } else {
      ArrayList<String> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
/*--------Here reading asset json file and add to array list-------*/
      AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

      try {
        for (String asset : assetManager.list("")) {
          if (asset.endsWith(".exolist.json")) {
            uriList.add("asset:///" + asset);
          }
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sample_list_load_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
      }
      uris = new String[uriList.size()];
      uriList.toArray(uris);
      Arrays.sort(uris);
    }

    ...
  }
```

This is modified code of above, here i am using api json data and pass it to intent.

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_chooser_activity);
    sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter();
    ExpandableListView sampleListView = findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
    sampleListView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
    sampleListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String dataUri = intent.getDataString();
    String[] uris;
    if (dataUri != null) {
      uris = new String[] {dataUri};
    } else {
      ArrayList<String> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
      //Here it pass JSON data------------------
      urlvideo = getIntent().getStringExtra("dataVideos");
      Log.e("TEST>>>>>>>", urlvideo);
      JSONArray jsonArray = null;
      try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(urlvideo);
        Log.e("TEST>>>>>>> 2222", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject explrObject = null;
        try {
          explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          Log.e("TEST>>>>>>> 3333", String.valueOf(explrObject));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        uriList.add(String.valueOf(explrObject));
      }

      uris = new String[uriList.size()];
      uriList.toArray(uris);
      Arrays.sort(uris);
    }
   ...
  }
```

i am getting these error

```
2020-04-09 13:25:04.803 2943-3129/com.tamoffline E/SampleChooserActivity: Error loading sample list: {"name":"YouTube DASH","samples":[{"name":"Google Glass (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=A2716F75795F5D2AF0E88962FFCD10DB79384F29.84308FF04844498CE6FBCE4731507882B8307798&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Glass (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=249B04F79E984D7F86B4D8DB48AE6FAF41C17AB3.7B9F0EC0505E1566E59B8E488E9419F253DDF413&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=B1C2A74783AC1CC4865EB312D7DD2D48230CC9FD.BD153B9882175F1F94BFE5141A5482313EA38E8D&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"}]}
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to {"name":"YouTube DASH","samples":[{"name":"Google Glass (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=A2716F75795F5D2AF0E88962FFCD10DB79384F29.84308FF04844498CE6FBCE4731507882B8307798&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Glass (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=249B04F79E984D7F86B4D8DB48AE6FAF41C17AB3.7B9F0EC0505E1566E59B8E488E9419F253DDF413&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=B1C2A74783AC1CC4865EB312D7DD2D48230CC9FD.BD153B9882175F1F94BFE5141A5482313EA38E8D&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"}]}
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:282)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:177)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:82)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:351)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:180)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at android.util.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:742)
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:782)
        at android.util.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:695)
        at android.util.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:334)
2020-04-09 13:25:04.806 2943-3129/com.tamoffline E/SampleChooserActivity:     at android.util.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:308)
        at android.util.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:277)
        at com.tamoffline.SampleChooserActivity$SampleListLoader.readSampleGroups(SampleChooserActivity.java:293)
        at com.tamoffline.SampleChooserActivity$SampleListLoader.doInBackground(SampleChooserActivity.java:276)
        at com.tamoffline.SampleChooserActivity$SampleListLoader.doInBackground(SampleChooserActivity.java:261)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: {"name":"YouTube DASH","samples":[{"name":"Google Glass (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (MP4,H264)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=A2716F75795F5D2AF0E88962FFCD10DB79384F29.84308FF04844498CE6FBCE4731507882B8307798&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Glass (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/bf5bb2419360daf1\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=249B04F79E984D7F86B4D8DB48AE6FAF41C17AB3.7B9F0EC0505E1566E59B8E488E9419F253DDF413&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"},{"name":"Google Play (WebM,VP9)","uri":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/api\/manifest\/dash\/id\/3aa39fa2cc27967f\/source\/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=B1C2A74783AC1CC4865EB312D7DD2D48230CC9FD.BD153B9882175F1F94BFE5141A5482313EA38E8D&key=ik0","extension":"mpd"}]}
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:429)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:280)
            ... 22 more
```

This is the sample data i am passing in Intent.

```
[
    {
      "name": "YouTube DASH",
      "samples": [
        {
          "name": "Google Glass (MP4,H264)",
          "uri": "https://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/bf5bb2419360daf1/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=51AF5F39AB0CEC3E5497CD9C900EBFEAECCCB5C7.8506521BFC350652163895D4C26DEE124209AA9E&key=ik0",
          "extension": "mpd"
        },
        {
          "name": "Google Play (MP4,H264)",
          "uri": "https://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/3aa39fa2cc27967f/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,fmp4_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=A2716F75795F5D2AF0E88962FFCD10DB79384F29.84308FF04844498CE6FBCE4731507882B8307798&key=ik0",
          "extension": "mpd"
        },
        {
          "name": "Google Glass (WebM,VP9)",
          "uri": "https://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/bf5bb2419360daf1/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=249B04F79E984D7F86B4D8DB48AE6FAF41C17AB3.7B9F0EC0505E1566E59B8E488E9419F253DDF413&key=ik0",
          "extension": "mpd"
        },
        {
          "name": "Google Play (WebM,VP9)",
          "uri": "https://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/dash/id/3aa39fa2cc27967f/source/youtube?as=fmp4_audio_clear,webm2_sd_hd_clear&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,source,id,as&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=19000000000&signature=B1C2A74783AC1CC4865EB312D7DD2D48230CC9FD.BD153B9882175F1F94BFE5141A5482313EA38E8D&key=ik0",
          "extension": "mpd"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You're apparently trying to use the entire JSON string as a URL instead of extracting `$[0].samples[0].uri`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- How do i extract samples uri?? i thought it would work as it use in AssestManager.

Comment: Use a JSON parser like Gson or JsonPath.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- hii.. do i have to deserialized  the json string which i passed in intent?? when i try to serialized using gson it gave me same error of above. For deserializing i post the new question. I have stick on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256944/how-to-deserialize-nested-json-array-in-java-with-gson